# is dask get_dummies supposed to work without persist?

Tags: python, dask

I am doing a (binary) prediction exercise with 47 variables but many millions of rows. So pure `pandas` (or now `pydaal`/`daal4py`) are not enough to set up the data; I am adapting a `dask` example to run locally. I am not scheduling tasks on a cluster but hope to stream my data and not hold all in memory.

Either for `dask-xgboost` or other dask-supported tools (in `scikit-learn`) I would need to convert my categorical variables into numerical values.

In Matthew Rocklin's [exercise](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/03/28/dask-xgboost), this is done in this line:

```
df2 = dd.get_dummies(df.categorize()).persist()
```

where `df` is a dask DataFrame and `dd` is the dask DataFrame module imported.

However, I would hope to avoid `persist()` in an earlier line (`df, is_delayed = dask.persist(df, is_delayed)` for Matthew), as I cannot do this in memory. Maybe this is why I get errors when I try to use the resulting DataFrame like this:

> Length mismatch: Expected axis has 39 elements, new values have 57
>   elements

How should one use `dask.dataframe.get_dummies()`, and in particular in a use case like mine?